# INotifyPropertyChanged - Changing PropertyName Causes No Effect

Tags: c#, winforms, inotifypropertychanged

I'm trying to bind my Winforms UI to my ViewModel. I was able to successfully update my ViewModel on UI changes and vice versa. However, I can't seem to understand what is the use of "PropertyName" used in PropertyChangedEventHandler since whatever I put there, it will always work. I don't know if I've already mixed things up since I've read a lot of articles about architectural patterns (MVP,MVC,MVVM,and MVP-VM (which is the one I was trying to do now) ).

Here is the part of the concerned code:

ViewModel

```
public class AdditionViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string augend;

    public string Augend
    {
        get { return augend; }
        set { 
                if(augend != value)
                {
                    augend = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ugend"));
                }
            }
    }
    private string addend;

    public string Addend
    {
        get { return addend; }
        set {
                if (addend != value)
                {
                    addend = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ddend"));
                }
            }
    }
    private string answer;

    public string Answer
    {
        get { return answer; }
        set {
                if(answer != value)
                {
                    answer = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("nswer"));
                }
            }
    }

    public AdditionClass additionClass;
    public AdditionViewModel(AdditionClass _additionClass)
    {
        additionClass = _additionClass;
    }
    public void Add()
    {
        //Some verifications first before inserting the value to the model class
        this.Augend = "1";//Testing for from code to UI binding
        additionClass.Augend = Double.Parse(Augend);
        additionClass.Addend = Double.Parse(Addend);
        //Somewhere here should implement the compute but since addition is a very simple task, no methods were called;
        Answer = additionClass.Answer.ToString();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.PropertyName);
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(e.PropertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    additionPresenter = new Presenter.AdditionPresenter(new ViewModel.AdditionViewModel(new Model.AdditionClass()));
    additionViewModelBindingSource.DataSource = additionPresenter.additionViewModel;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    additionPresenter.AddButtonClick();
}
```

Presenter:

```
public AdditionPresenter(AdditionViewModel _additionViewModel)
{
    additionViewModel = _additionViewModel;
}

public void AddButtonClick()
{
    additionViewModel.Add();
}
```

One of the auto-generated code from Designer (Binding on UI):

```
// 
// textBox1
// 
this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.additionViewModelBindingSource, "Addend", true));
this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 41);
this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
```

As can be seen on the ViewModel, I've omitted all the "A"s at the start of each PropertyName in the setters but the application is still working. 
Sorry for the long code pastes. I can't seem to find a better explanation than just to show you the implementation

Comment: Because you using `BindingSource` as "ViewModel" object in the form. Change databinding to not using `BindingSource` => `textBox1.DataBinding.Add("Text", additionViewModel, "Addend", true)` and then `NotifyPropertyChanged` event will have affect - or will not have affect in your case

Comment: So does it mean that by using a `BindingSource` as the `BindingSource` of the control, it already enabled the two way binding of the control to the object? And by using the ViewModel as the `BindingSource` as you said, will make the `PropertyName` matter and affect the binding?

Comment: I've actually tested what you said and by using the ViewModel for databinding instead of a `BindingSource`, it is now required for the `PropertyName` to be the same as the one in the `DataMember` at databinding.  Since both of them works, which one is more preferred? or should I just post another thread for my new question.

Comment: I think if you create another thread you will get more answers, I hope. On my own opinion I use `BindingSource` in the cases where UI have grid and currently selected item information on the same view/form - I use `Current` property of `BindingSource`. But in others cases I prefer instance of ViewModel which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. That gives me "feeling" that I have control. I am not sure, but after testing seems like `BindingSource` will loop all ViewModel properties after every update of some property.

Comment: @Fabio I edited the post and provided a detailed description about **Having wrong property names in PropertyChanged event why do I still have two-way data-binding?** You can read the source codes using links that I provide in the answer. Hope you find the answer helpful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=net-6.0) is not necessary for data binding, but it enables two-way data binding.
In fact as mentioned in documentations: *The INotifyPropertyChanged interface is used to notify clients, typically binding clients, that a property value has changed.*

In simple (one-way) data binding, when you change the bound property of control, value push into the bound property of your object and it doesn't need `INotifyPropertyChanges`.

But without `INotifyPropertyChanged`, if you change the value of bound property of your object using code, new value doesn't push into your control's bound property.

---

**Having wrong property names in PropertyChanged event why do I still have two-way data-binding?**

In fact it's because of using `BindingSource` as source of data-boinding, as mentioned by [Fabio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253278/inotifypropertychanged-changing-propertyname-causes-no-effect#comment56249739_34253278) in comments.

When using `BindingSource` as data source of your data-bindings, it's enough for your objects to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise `PropertyChaned` event (even with empty or wrong property name) and then the `BindingSource` (actually its inner `BindingList<T>`) [subscribes](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/BindingList.cs,8f4097cabc74b7b0) for `PropertyChaned` event and when [received](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/BindingList.cs,e757be5fba0e6000) the event it checkes if you didn't passed a correct property name or if you passed empty property name it the will call [`ResetBindings()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132702(v=vs.110).aspx) that consequencly causes a control bound to the `BindingSource` to reread all the items in the list and refresh their displayed values.
Correct names in `PropertyChanged` causes the normal behavior of two-way data-binding and also causes raising [`ListChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.listchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event with correct property in `e.PropertyDescriptor`.

Comment: I actually tested the "from bound property of object to bound property of control" through the line at View model `this.Augend = "1";//Testing for from code to UI binding` and it works since after clicking the button, one of the textboxes value will be "1". What bothers me really is the `OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ugend"));` "PropertyName" parameter. I thought it is the one binding to the `textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.additionViewModelBindingSource, "Addend", true));`.

Comment: I tested 2 things. Using your model directly, it needs null or empty string or exact names of properties to work. Using `BindingSource` it needs only raising the event with any name.

Comment: I personally prefer to implement the interface correctly and also use `BindingSource`. Using binding source you will have a good design-time support.

Comment: @Lawrence I edited the post and provided a detailed description about **Having wrong property names in PropertyChanged event why do I still have two-way data-binding?** You can read the source codes using links that I provide in the answer. Hope you find the answer helpful :)

Comment: Thanks! It is definitely helpful :). So this means that I can still maintain the `BindingSource` to have that **good design-time support** and at the same time, provide the right `PropertyName` in order to save resources by not reading all the items in the list?